# How to put a quote in article reference?

Tags: bibliographies

I want to add the following content in my *.bib* file.

```
@article{xxx,
author = {xxx},
title = {xxx},
journal = {xxx},
volume = {CIVR '07},
number = 1,
pages = {111},
year = 2007
}
```

In the **volume** line, I want to put a single-quote `'`. But LaTex think it is an incorrect syntax. I tried to escape it with `\`, but it does not work.

Comment: Which bibliography style are you using. With `unsrt` I don't get error.

Comment: My impression is that you're referring to the text editor program, rather than to LaTeX; use `CIVR \rq 07` in order to fool it.

Comment: @egreg, errr, you are right. LaTeX did not complain about the quote. It was the editor. I thought it has LaTeX syntax check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information and a compilable minimal example (`\documentclass{}...\begin{document}...\end{document}`) is needed to solve your problem. For instance, you do not say which bibliography system you are using. The following code demonstrates that BibLaTeX seemingly has no problem whatsoever with that syntax:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[
style=authoryear,
sorting=nyt,
backend=biber
]{biblatex}


\bibliography{test}

\begin{document}
\section{Intro}
A test citation \textcite{Test}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

With bib entry

```
@ARTICLE{Test,
  author = {Test},
  year = {1999},
  title = {A test title},
  journal = {A test journal},
  volume = {CIVR '07},
  pages = {1-100},
  timestamp = {2015.04.07}
}
```